# How to write a portion of vector (or structure) with fwrite

Tags: c, fwrite

Using fwrite I discovered that I can write a portion of a vector (or structure). Ex:

```
fwrite (a, sizeof(a[0]), sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]), fp);
```

writes in the stream fp (previously opened), all the elements of the vector a. If I want to write a part of the vector (for example the first 5 elements), I can write:

```
fwrite (a, sizeof(a[0]), 5, fp);
```

The question is: How can I go about writing two elements like a[2] and a[3]? Or the last element of the vector?

I need this because I opened the stream as "rb+", so I would like to add data and not rewrite them all.

Comment: With `fwrite (a+2, sizeof(a[0]), 2, fp);` But you need to seek to the right place in the file first, if you are over-writing 2 elements.

Comment: So it's about using pointer arithmetic on the first parameter.

Comment: Or you could use `&a[2]`.